# Wifi access point with USB-OTG ethernet?

Tags: tethering, usb-peripherals

I want my phone to act as a ethernet capable wifi access point (WAN via ethernet).

When I use USB-OTG with an ethernet USB adapter attached to my Galaxy Nexus (non-rooted stock Jelly Bean) I get regular internet access just fine. Only thing I'm wondering about is the fact that 3G is shown in the status bar although mobile data connection is disabled. The connection goes over ethernet.

My Problem appears when I want to share this connection via wifi (hotspot). The hotspot is enabled and the other device (or whatever) is connected but it doesn´t get internet access...

Is this a known problem? Any ideas how to get this working?

***Edit:*** It's not about 3G tethering, thats works fine. The problem is tethering while the phone is connected with the LAN over an RJ45-Ethernet adapter.

Comment: What adapter are you using? I tried to get internet over Ethernet with the Nexus, but it didn't work.

Comment: Just my thought:-While enabling inbuilt WiFi tethering the hotspot interface would have binded with 3G baseband interface normally..In your case you may want to bind your internet providing ethernet interface with hotspot interface.Any private app could help.

Comment: @Rilwan do you any app which can help with this?

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)

Answer (score 1):

Some carriers disable 3G tethering in order to make more money, so if your carrier has installed software on your phone before hand to stop tethering the only way to make it work is to root your device and install an application that will allow you to do that.

The reason why it only connects is maybe because creating a hotspot to share files/resources over a LAN is allowed but to access the internet isn't. Right now, the FCC is forcing Verizon in particular to allow users to be able to share their phone's 3G internet.

Comment: in general it´s not about 3g tethering, thats works fine. the problem is tethering while the phone is connected with the LAN over an RJ45-Ethernet adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found a solution, however it's quite complicated to set up and you need to configure the wifi clients (i.e. Chromecast won't work with that). I still hope to find a better solution.

1. Connect ethernet, start hotspot as usual
2. Install any HTTP Proxy Server app from Google Play. "Servers Ultimate" does among many others also contain a http proxy.
3. Start the server on a port of your choosing (default HTTP ports are not available without root), usually leave everything else as it is.
4. On your wifi client that is connected with your phone's hotspot, go into the proxy settings (Windows: Control panel -> Internet -> Internet options -> Connections -> LAN Settings -> Use Proxy Server; Android: Wifi Settings -> Long press on name -> Change network -> Advanced -> Manual Proxy)
5. Set the proxy you've just created. The IP adress will be the local ip of your phone which acts as a gateway within your wifi hotspot. It is shown in the "Info" section of the Proxy Server app at the bottom (last IPv4 entry!).
6. You've finally got internet on your wifi clients!

Comment: So I am wondering if it is possible to share phone's internet via usb-ethernet adapter with a PC?

Comment: @cpz I've successfully tried that once. If I recall correctly, you can use precisely the setup I described, yet instead of the wifi clients you need to point the _ethernet client_ (the PC) to the proxy server you've set up on your phone. I've actually found an even better & more complicated solution where the clients are configured automatically (proxy script); if you're interested, I'll post it somewhere. However, this still doesn't work with Chromecast (or the like?), as it does not support proxy scripts, alas.