# USB tethered device cannot communicate with WLAN hotspotted device on the same Android phone

Tags: connection-issues, wifi-hotspot, usb-tethering

Here I have one Android phone, the `provider`, a device, `usb`, connecting to it through USB tethering, and a device `wlan` connecting through WLAN hotspot.

So once `usb` connected, it got assigned an IP in the `192.168.42.0/24` block. `provider`, acting as router, had an IP in there, of course. When I connected `wlan`, it got an IP in the `192.168.43.0/24` block, and `provider` had one IP in there too.

Now, I can't see the other from either device, either by scanning both blocks, or by directly `ping`ing or `ssh`ing into the other device. All I can see is the device I'm operating on, and the two `gateways`, which are essentialy the same `provider`.

I suspected it's a limitation of the ROM I used at first, but after flashing a custom ROM the problem persists. Is this a native limitation of the Android OS? As far as I remember iOS didnt't have this problem, and a USB tethered device can communicate with a WLAN connected one. Thank you.

Comment: It's because hosts on different subnets cannot communicate with each other. `192.168.42.0/24` and `192.168.43.0/24` are two different subnets. iOS might be using same subnet for both USB tethering and hotspot, I'm not aware of. Or you can add a static route to setup [Routing Between Multiple Subnets](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/311917/262728). Your question is more about networking than Android.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks for pointing out! You're right about subnet communications. However, after adding a route on one of the devices, with the gateway being either address of `provider`, it can still not ping the other. I'll go further to figure out. It also seems true that iOS uses the same subnet (172.20.10.0/28) for both USB tethering and hotspot.

Comment: Here is [a solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/106625), and the question is largely the same.

Comment: Adding some routes or setting up proxy ARP is better than using third party tools to divert the traffic in userspace.

Comment: Agreed. I'll try and find a way.